# Creating a link with HTML helper tags

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a Link using HTML helper tags. According to the code given below, when the user clicks on the link, the page will navigate to another view which is called `Hello`.

```
       @Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Hello", new {  id=item.pk  })
```

But, what i want to do is to Call a JS method and open a div in the same page. how can i do this ? **example** : Show and Hide some controls when the user clicks on the edit

```
@foreach (var item in Model.exampleAll)
{

@Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Hello", new {  id=item.pk  }) 
}
```

Comment: for that you don't need an action designated. just an anchor with no href and JS event handler

Comment: But, i also need to get hold of the `id=item.pk `. How should i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mundane as this sounds, i'd use a html anchor

```
<a href='' id='@(item.pk)' class='itemsList'> click me </a>
```

and then a JQuery Event Handler

```
$('.itemsList').click(function(){
      var currentId = this.id; // get id of object that was clicked
      // populate or make visible your div here
});
```

It doesn't feel like the 'MVC WAY' but you need nothing more.

**important note:** If you don't want to do any navigating with the anchor/link, using an Html.ActionLink seems overkill.

Comment: Can you suggest me the best way to grab that primary key of a record and pass it on to a function?

Comment: @user1315906, please explain. item.pk isn't populated yet? if not, what's your data source? EF?

Comment: Item.Pk is the primary key and its populated. I just want to know how to pass it to the Jquery function ?

Comment: @user1315906 OIC, use var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

Comment: I get this error `The name 'item' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25051/discussion-between-dave-a-and-user1315906)

Answer (score 2):

Change the ActionLink to be:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Hello","YourController", new { onclick = "yourFunction();"})
```

Or even better add a js function to intercept the click of your link, here's with JQuery:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Hello","YourController", new { id= "someLink"}) 

$('#someLink').click(function() { alert('hello'); });
```

Edit: If you need to apply a function to more than one element use the css class as the selector, change the actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Hello","YourController", new { id= item.pk, @class = "classname"}) 

$('.classname').click(function() { alert(this.id); });
```

Comment: Well `someclick` in the `ActionLink ` is the primary key. So i need to grab that value, and pass it to the function. How can i do that according to your 2nd method ?

Comment: i like your JQ better. much simpler than mine. But would having an actual href rendered be wrong for this example?

Comment: Hi, I think it's not too bad if used as an anchor. Btw the same snippet can be applied to any element with a click event.

Comment: Actually, your example works in every way, except he cant get it to NOT navigate. I bet there's a way to stop it.

Comment: I got the answer, but borrowed a lil JQ from you, so you get my +1

Comment: to avoid the navigation to the new page use change the function to $('.classname').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); alert(this.id); });     http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/